# Two instances of rspec, do they interfere with each other?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I've been fiddling with Guard trying to get it to load rspec tests, but it's throwing some errors about the test schema.

I realised that I had rspec being run on the whole test suite (takes ~30 mins) in another terminal window in the background. I looked and these tests were also throwing errors (not expected to).

Is there simply one 'test' database that both rspec executions were messing with—and therefore causing each other to fail? Or can I run simultaneous processes without worry?